# Connecting to memcached using a websocket connected client

Tags: amazon-web-services, tcp, websocket, memcached

Does anyone know if a memcached client can connect to the memcached using a websocket connection? The reason I ask is that we want to use AWS's Application Load Balancer which only supports TCP through a websocket connection. Our app uses TCP to retrieve properties from the cache and we want to put them behind the ALB for scale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Websockets are not plain TCP sockets but they consist of an initial handshake using HTTP and the messages itself are put into special frames. This means that to communicate with some server using Websockets the server must understand Websockets. Memcached does not implement a Websockets interface which means it is not possible to communicate with memcached using Websockets.

But, according to [the documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/classicloadbalancer/), the the AWS Classic Load Balancer does support pure TCP load balancing so you might use this instead of the Application Load Balancer.

Comment: Right, we are currently using an ELB and wanted to move to an ALB to use its smarter healthcheck mechanism. Thanks for the detailed response.